PropertyReferenceException: No property 'reg' found for type 'UserVideoHashTag'
I want to sort by reg_dtime(DateTime) of Object....
But, it works "reg: DESC" ..
Why is the underbar missing?
How can I do? Please help me..
my springboot is 2.7.3
// service
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, maxResults, Sort.Direction.DESC,"reg_dtime");
Page<UserVideoHashTag> userVideoHashTags = userVideoHashtagRepository.findAllByHashTagId(hashTagId, pageable);

// jpaRepository
@Repository
public interface UserVideoHashtagRepository extends JpaRepository<UserVideoHashTag, Long> {
    Page<UserVideoHashTag> findAllByHashTagId(Long hashTagId, Pageable pageable);
}

// Object(JPA Entity)
@DynamicInsert
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Table(name="user_video_hash_tag")
@Where(clause = "delete_yn = 0")
public class UserVideoHashTag extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_video_id")
    private UserVideo userVideo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hash_tag_id")
    private HashTag hashTag;

    @Column(name = "delete_yn")
    private Boolean deleteYn;

    public void delete(){
        this.deleteYn = true;
    }
}

this is error log.
it said I
2024-04-04 11:07:53.984 ERROR 19558 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'reg' found for type 'UserVideoHashTag'] with root cause
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'reg' found for type 'UserVideoHashTag'
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:438) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:414) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
String propertyName = Introspector.decapitalize(name);
TypeInformation<?> propertyType = owningType.getProperty(propertyName);

if (propertyType == null) {
    // error point
    throw new PropertyReferenceException(propertyName, owningType, base);
}

When I debugged that, Introspector.decapitalize is wrong
